# Named Range in Excel gets the count but not the value

Tags: vba, excel

I created a Named range for a particular column of the table below (Table Name: "Table2").

[image: Data Table]

In Another cell (Cell F23), I created a named range "DNR_Product" using Formulas > Name Manager > New
Provided the following in the refers to formula box:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet3!F23,0,0,COUNTA(Table2[Product]),1)
```

Name Manager looks like this:
[image: Name Manager screenshot]
I do not see any values in the named range. However when I run the following snippet, the count of the named range comes up correctly (in this case 13).

```
Sub printRangeCount()
Dim strRangeName As String
strRangeName = "DNR_Product"

Dim oSht As Worksheet
Set oSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

Dim iCount As Integer
iCount = oSht.Range(strRangeName).Rows.Count
MsgBox iCount


End Sub
```

But the cell it self does not have the data that I expect.
[image: Blank Named Range Data]

Is there something wrong in the approach?

## Updated

The values I expect should look something like below:
[image]

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I updated my question to show the expected data values. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to create a new named range for your table - just name the table (it's in your name manager as Table2). It's available in VBA as a ListObject member of the Worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Your not actually telling VBA to put that information anywhere, it performs the count and returns the value 13, but then you don't tell it to put it in a cell.

`oSht.Range("F23").value = iCount` would place it in the highlighted cell in your picture (or you can use the correct name range)

Comment: but that can't be achieved just by a formula. I will need to use VBA. I thought this can be achieved by formula it self. The VBA script that I had written is a tests to confirm that my named range is actually getting updated according to the data table.

Comment: If you want to populate a cell with a formula you will have to put the formula in the cell(s). Your named range is referring to the contents of the cells below F23 (assuming F23 was active when you defined the range, since you used a relative reference), not the contents of the table column.